# Connection to HTTPSConnectionPool broken by ReadTimeoutError (Retrying)

Tags: pandas, urllib3, nominatim, connection-pool

When executed, the code below takes a long time.

```
for index,row in d_airbnb.iterrows(): #Loop for para varrer cada linha.
    latitude = row['latitude']
    longitude = row['longitude']
    location = geo_locator.reverse((latitude, longitude),language='en', exactly_one=True,timeout=5) #Usamos o metodo geolocator.reverse() para descobrir se cada zipcode é válido.
    address = location.address
    if row['neighbourhood'] not in address:
        d_airbnb.at[index, 'zipcode'] = '00000' #Caso o zipcode não corresponder ao bairro que o locator.reverse me forneceu pela API, então o zipcode é invalido e inconsistente. Por isso trocamos por "00000".
```

I tried increasing the timeout to 2 seconds, but it still takes a long time and produces some timeout errors:

```
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying 
(Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): 
Read timed out. (read timeout=1)")'
```

What causes this, and how to treat it?
Is there another way to check these zipcodes faster? There are 70'000 lines and 29 columns in my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements are specified that do not allow for intensive use: **maximum of 1 request per second** ([click](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/)). So, you can set sleep to `1 second` and store data to prevent re-downloading of data you have already obtained.

There are two more options ([click](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/#:%7E:text=Alternatives%20/%20Third%2Dparty%20providers)).

1. Use other available  commercial third-party providers
2. Install your instance of Nominatim (not recommended for your case in my opinion)