# urllib3 warning ReadTimeoutError while connecting to Nominatim's geolocator

Tags: python, urllib3, httpconnection, nominatim, geolocator

The code below code to extract pincodes, but raises the error below. How to work around this?

```
def get_zipcode(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field):
    location = geolocator.reverse(str(df[lat_field]) + "," + str(df[lon_field]))
    # print(location)    #-- uncomment this in case of checking the output
    #return location.raw['address']['postcode']
    
    if location == None:
        return "none"
    else:
        return location.raw['address'].get('postcode')

geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent="MyGeocodingScript")


zipcode = df.apply(get_zipcode, axis=1, geolocator=geolocator, lat_field='GPS_Lat', lon_field='GPS_Lon')
```

Error:

```
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)")': /reverse?lat=11.2181948&lon=78.1811652&format=json&addressdetails=1
```

Comment: Helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78163113/12846804

Comment: it isnt clear, where should i declare the parameters?

Comment: @OCa even with the solution mentioned it isnt working, any other workaround?

Comment: Well according to Nominatim policy (link in the answer above) you might be attempting an "Unacceptable Use" ("searching for complete lists of postcodes") and in there they link you to another service to use instead. That may be the main problem. I am not sure what parameter you refer to.

Comment: Doesn't your call work for a single zipcode request, then fail when using `apply`?